# Including jQuery to website will affect whole website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bought dating site software called eMeeting. I tried to add a custom javascript slider to the header.  The slider needs jquery library to work, but when I include the library, other scripts from the webpage stop working. But if I comment the line below (located in sliders js file)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Other javascripts from the page will work again.

I have done an example of my problem to [here.](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/286010-problem-with-dating-software-when-importing-jquery-library/)

It would be really nice if someone has some time to help me or give me some suggestions. Also the webpage is http://flirt.ee

Best Regards,
Mairo

Comment: Probably it's a conflict issue; jQuery 1.3.2 is very old, please consider to refactor the site code by upgrading jQuery and related plugins

Comment: see your error message on your broswer console

Comment: Make sure that you are not already including jquery somewhere.

Comment: I tried with the jQuery 2.0.2 and still got the same result. Also browsers conseole wont return anything about this. I havent included jquery already.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a conflict with another library.
Add this right after you include jquery:

```
<script>$.noConflict();</script>
```

Comment: After adding this after the include jQuery other scripts will work, but not the slider.

Comment: No, the console wont return anything related to javascript.

Comment: Try using a newer version of jquery e.g. `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and include the `$.noConflict()` part directly after you insert jQuery. Also make sure that you don't use it multiple times (currently there're two).